# Unable to handle errors in javascript promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Why doesn't it run the code "console.log(err)" below? but instead returns "TypeError: Cannot create property 'uncaught' on string 'error in promise'"

```
function abc() {
    throw "error in promise";
    return 123;
};
abc().catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
}).then ( abcMessage =>
    console.log(abcMessage)
)
```

Comment: Don’t throw strings; throw errors. `new Error("error in promise")`

Comment: thanks! amended it to new Error("error in promise") and the error is gone but now instead of running console.log(err) it throws the error Error: error in promise before it reaches console.log(err)

Comment: where's the promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` and `.catch` require a Promise to be constructed. You are not returning a promise. The promise callback (executor) takes two arguments, a resolver, and a rejecter. Depending on what happens in the code, you may need to call resolve if everything goes right, or reject if something goes wrong.

```js
function abc() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject(123)
  });
};


abc()
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  })
  .then(abcMessage => {
    console.log(abcMessage)
  });
```

```html
new Error("error in promise")
```

Comment: What you call the "promise callback" actually has an official name, which is **executor**.